# Unit test fails when running all, but passes when running individually

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have about 12 unit tests for different scenarios, and I need to call one async method in these tests (sometimes multiple times in one test). When I do "Run all", 3 of them will always fail. If I run them one by one using "Run selected test", they will pass. The exception in output I'm getting is this:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not
>   stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are
>   stopped before completion.

I can't really share the code, as it's quite big and I don't know where to start, so here is example:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SampleTest()
{
    var someProvider = new SomeProvider();

    var result = await someProvider.IsSomethingValid();

    Assert.IsTrue(result == SomeProvider.Status.Valid);

    NetworkController.Disable();

    result = await someProvider.IsSomethingValid();

    Assert.IsTrue(result == SomeProvider.Status.Valid);

    NetworkController.Enable();
}
```

EDIT:
The other 2 failing methods set time to the future and to the past respectively.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SetTimeToFutureTest()
{
    var someProvider = new SomeProvider();

    var today = TimeProvider.UtcNow().Date;

    var result = await someProvider.IsSomethingValid();

    Assert.IsTrue(result == SomeProvider.Status.Valid);

    TimeProvider.SetDateTime(today.AddYears(1));

    var result2 = await someProvider.IsSomethingValid();

    Assert.IsTrue(result2 == SomeProvider.Status.Expired);
}
```

Where TimeProvider looks like this:

```
public static class TimeProvider
{
    /// <summary> Normally this is a pass-through to DateTime.Now, but it can be overridden with SetDateTime( .. ) for testing or debugging.
    /// </summary>
    public static Func<DateTime> UtcNow = () => DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary> Set time to return when SystemTime.UtcNow() is called.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetDateTime(DateTime newDateTime)
    {
        UtcNow = () => newDateTime;
    }

    public static void ResetDateTime()
    {
        UtcNow = () => DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        TimeProvider.ResetDateTime();
    }
```

Other  methods are similar, I will simulate time/date change, etc.

I tried calling the method synchronously by getting .Result() out of it, etc, but it didn't help. I read ton material on the web about this but still struggling.

Did anyone run into the same problem? Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it has nothing to do with shared instances or static classes (`NetworkController` e.g.)?

Comment: @bashis 2 of the failing methods don't call NetworkController.

Comment: It seems your methods are dependent , you have to identify the correct order where  method should lies in the list.

Comment: @user969153 not much help can be provided without proper context.

Comment: I have had this issue before and it boiled down to two tests running at the same time using some shared piece of code that ended up interfering with each other.

Comment: I added the 2 other methods. They should be not be depended, as they are only validating something in different scenarios (time in the future for example), and the whole logic is stateless

Comment: @user969153 nope the test are running async and accessing a shared static resource. they will conflict with each other. avoid using the static class and create a service that can be mocked and injected into the dependent classes so that your unit tests can be tested in isolation.

Comment: Nkosi are you referring to the TimeProvider?

Comment: @user969153, both the time provider and network controller look like static classes. Wile you may be creating new instance of the SUT it is dependent on external class that is being modified while testing which also exposes that system under test is very brittle

Comment: @Nkosi Both TimeProvider and NetworkController are only for unit testing purposes and have no real use in the library itself. Actually, I found TimeProvider here on SO as a good way of testing time changes in unit tests. I commented out all TimeProvider calls and changed NetworkController class to not be static, and I have the same result.

Comment: @user969153 then show the method under test that fails as the problem exists there. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202924/unit-test-failing-only-when-run-on-the-build-server/36219999#36219999

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you're doing with your test initialization or cleanup but it could be that since all of your test methods are attempting to run asynchronously, the test runner is not allowing all tasks to finish before performing cleanup.

Are the same few methods failing when you run all of the tests or is it random?  Are you sure you are doing unit testing and not integration testing?  The class "NetworkController" gives me the impression that you may be doing more of an integration test.  If that were the case and you are using a common class, provider, service, or storage medium (database, file system) then interactions or state changes caused by one method could affect another test method's efficacy.

Comment: I added TestCleanup method in my second edit. It only resets the TimeProvider. There is no test init, I init everything in test methods as local variables. I had test init before, with SomeProvider class initialization there, but it didn't help.

Comment: NetworkController class just changes PC's IP address to simulate no internet access. The purpose of the library is to return with different status when connected/disconnected and in different times - all the unit tests try to simulate this - either time change, or network change, or both.

Answer (score 1):

When running tests in async/await mode, you will incur some lag.  It looks like all your processing is happening in memory.  They're probably passing one an one-by-one basis because the lag time is minimal. When running multiple in async mode, the lag time is sufficient to cause differentiation in the time results.

I've run into this before doing NUnit tests run by NCrunch where a DateTime component is being tested.  You can mitigate this by reducing the scope of your validation / expiration logic to match to second instead of millisecond, as long as this is permissible within your acceptance criteria.  I can't tell from your code what the logic is driving validation status or expiration date, but I'm willing to bet the async lag is the root cause of the test failure when run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Both tests shown use the same static TimeProvider, thus interference by methods like ResetDateTime in the cleanup and     TimeProvider.SetDateTime(today.AddYears(1)); in a test are to be expected. Also the NetworkController seems to be a static resource, and connecting/disconnecting it could interfere with your tests.

You can solve the issues in several ways:

- get rid of static resources, use instances instead
- lock the tests such that only one test can be run at a time

Aside from that, almost every test framework offers more than just Assert.IsTrue. Doesn't your framework offer an Assert.AreEqual? That improves readabilty. Also, with more than one Assert in a test, custom messages indicating which of the test failed (or that an Assert is for pre-condition, not the actual test) are recommended.